# Using Ant with Flex

Tags: eclipse, apache-flex, ant, flex4, flash-builder

I'm having problems setting up Ant to use with Flex. I install it fine but I get this error when I try and check the install: Unable to locate tools.jar.

From what I've read, I just need to point JAVA_HOME to the directory that contains the jdk. Unfortunately, I'm not sure I know which jre I'm using in Eclipse and also, I do a search for tools.jar on my machine and it's not there???

I have a C:\Program Files\Java directory and there is this in there:

- j2re1.4.2_05
- jdk1.6.0_03
- jre1.6.0.23

In Eclipse --> Windows --> Preferences --Java --> Installed JREs, it's pointing to here:

eclipse-host-distro, C:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe Flash Builder Plug-in\eclipse-host-distro

Am I not working with a full JRE?

Any tips are greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just specify your JAVA_HOME path as `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_03\` and everything should be good as long as the JDK was properly installed.  If that doesn't work, [get the latest](https://cds.sun.com/is-bin/INTERSHOP.enfinity/WFS/CDS-CDS_Developer-Site/en_US/-/USD/ViewProductDetail-Start?ProductRef=jdk-6u24-oth-JPR@CDS-CDS_Developer) and try again.

Comment: My JDK was not properly installed. Getting the latest did the trick. Thank you very much!